# Sum decimal numbers in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field that is a string with numbers in it. I need to sum all these numbers

The table contains some information about servers. It includes the server name in one field and the drive IDs and sizes in the other filed. I need to sum all the drive sizes together to determine the used disk space.

I have tried doing some replace functions and get very close, but cannot get exactly what I need.

This is an example of the data contained in the filed:

```
C: 20479.7 MB D: 119495.4 MB I: 255996.6 MB J: 61436.0 MB K: 255996.6 MB U: 61436.0 MB X: 51191.4 MB

SELECT 
  [host]
  ,[Drive_Info]
  ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Drive_Info], 'C:', ''), ':', '+'), 'MB', ''), ' ', '')
FROM [dbo].[DB]
```

Comment: Can you share what your desired results from this SQL would be given that sample record. It's not clear.

Comment: It would take the 7 values out of the string and add them together.

20479.7 + 119495.4 + 255996.6 + 61436 + 255996.6 + 61436 + 51191.4 =  826031.7

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016 (and later) you can use `string_split` to break down your string and get each element. Then you can use `sum` with `try_cast` to sum only numerical values.

Here is a quick example of this approach:

```
declare @string varchar(max) ='C: 20479.7 MB D: 119495.4 MB I: 255996.6 MB J: 61436.0 MB K: 255996.6 MB U: 61436.0 MB X: 51191.4 MB'

select sum(try_cast([value] as decimal(10,2))) as SumOfAllValues 
from string_split(@string, ' ')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [PatternSplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns) it's as easy as:

```
declare @string varchar(8000) ='C: 20479.7 MB D: 119495.4 MB I: 255996.6 MB J: 61436.0 MB K: 255996.6 MB U: 61436.0 MB X: 51191.4 MB';

SELECT SUM(CAST(ps.Item AS DECIMAL(10,2))) 
FROM   dbo.patternsplitcm(@string,'[0-9.]') AS ps
WHERE  ps.[matched] = 1;
```